# Practical applications of confluent persistence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, persistence, purely-functional

I'm just reading [Purely Functional Worst Case Constant Time Catenable Sorted Lists](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/esa06trees.pdf) by Brodal et al. and their introduction to the different kinds of persistence in the context of data structures leaves me with an obvious question:

> **Confluent persistence:** all the versions can be updated and queried and additionally, two versions can be combined to produce a new
>   version. Note that in this case it is possible to create in polynomial
>   time an exponentially sized structure by repeatedly joining it with
>   itself.

What are the practical applications of being able to create an "exponentially-sized" structure in polynomial time by repeatedly joining it with itself?

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example use case.  Imagine a general-purpose "sequence" datatype being used as an array in a situation where the array is expected to be sparse (ie, most of the elements will contain the same value, with a relatively few spots set to some other value).  If the sequence datatype has this property, then you can build the (possibly very large) array using the technique you mention, and it will still be reasonably space and time efficient under this usage.

Sure, you could make a special-purpose datatype especially for sparse arrays, and it would probably be a little more space and time efficient than the general-purpose datatype, but the point is that the general-purpose datatype adapts gracefully enough to this usage pattern that you might not even need to make the special-purpose datatype.

(Admittedly, this example is about confluent persistence in general, not about the "sorted lists" of the paper.  Then again, in the paper, they were making the remark in question about confluent persistence in general, not specifically about their own data structure.)

Answer (score 1):

I did not read the paper but by seeing the definition of Confluent Persistence you have provided I can correlate that to a Data Structure such as [Binomial Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) where in the merge operation is logarithmic running time and it is highly suitable for sets union kind of Algorithms. As Trees grows exponentially and considering a Binomial Heap we may have several of them and each one of them can be merged in polynomial time. Carrying out the union operation would be the the best application that I feel for such kind of Data Structures and that too in polynomial time.

Comment: I had a similar thought initially but I don't think set union can introduce sharing because it removes duplicates, i.e. the union of a set A with itself is no bigger than A.

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests that you read the paper as saying that this property is an advantage of data structures that exhibit that type of persistence. Looking at the paper, I don't think that's what the authors intended - it is just a somewhat counterintuitive property of such data structures that they wanted to point out for fun and pleasure of the reader.

As a further note, the exponential size that the authors talk about is, I think, the "mathematical" size (number of nodes in an abstract sense), not the size in memory - it wouldn't be possible to access or write an exponential number of memory locations in polynomial time!